# Shift individual list element to the right

Tags: python

I've been having this problem (below).

What I want to achieve is to shift each individual element in the list to the right and create a list/dictionary of lists of the possible combinations.

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
{[1,2,3,4,5],
[2,1,3,4,5],
[2,3,1,4,5],
[2,3,4,1,5],
[2,3,4,5,1],
[1,3,2,4,5],
[1,3,4,2,5],
[1,3,4,5,2],
[1,2,4,3,5],
.
.
.
#until final possible combination
}
```

It doesn't have to be in the same order as the example above. I just want to be able to get a long list/dictionary of all possible order of combinations of `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's `itertools.combinations()`.

Comment: @jasonharper: `combinations` isn't order-sensitive like that. Looks like `permutations` use case.

Comment: @thedeaflistener great job on making me examine the pattern, only at the end i find it wasn't necessary XD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Permutations work well and got me what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `permutations()` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import permutations
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in permutations(l):
    print(list(l))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 5, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
[1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
[1, 4, 3, 5, 2]
[1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 5, 3, 2]
[1, 5, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 5, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
[2, 1, 4, 5, 3]
[2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 5, 4, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
[2, 3, 5, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 1, 5, 3]
[2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
[2, 4, 5, 1, 3]
[2, 4, 5, 3, 1]
[2, 5, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 5, 1, 4, 3]
[2, 5, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 5, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 5, 4, 1, 3]
[2, 5, 4, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
[3, 1, 2, 5, 4]
[3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
[3, 1, 4, 5, 2]
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 5, 4, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
[3, 2, 1, 5, 4]
[3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
[3, 2, 4, 5, 1]
[3, 2, 5, 1, 4]
[3, 2, 5, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
[3, 4, 1, 5, 2]
[3, 4, 2, 1, 5]
[3, 4, 2, 5, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
[3, 5, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 5, 1, 4, 2]
[3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
[3, 5, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 5, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 5, 4, 2, 1]
[4, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[4, 1, 2, 5, 3]
[4, 1, 3, 2, 5]
[4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
[4, 1, 5, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 5, 3, 2]
[4, 2, 1, 3, 5]
[4, 2, 1, 5, 3]
[4, 2, 3, 1, 5]
[4, 2, 3, 5, 1]
[4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
[4, 2, 5, 3, 1]
[4, 3, 1, 2, 5]
[4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
[4, 3, 2, 5, 1]
[4, 3, 5, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 5, 2, 1]
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 1, 3, 2]
[4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
[4, 5, 2, 3, 1]
[4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 1, 2, 4, 3]
[5, 1, 3, 2, 4]
[5, 1, 3, 4, 2]
[5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
[5, 1, 4, 3, 2]
[5, 2, 1, 3, 4]
[5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
[5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[5, 2, 4, 1, 3]
[5, 2, 4, 3, 1]
[5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
[5, 3, 1, 4, 2]
[5, 3, 2, 1, 4]
[5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
[5, 3, 4, 1, 2]
[5, 3, 4, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 4, 1, 3, 2]
[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]
[5, 4, 2, 3, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 1, 2]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```